# jQuery overlay onclick

Tags: jquery, overlay, modal-dialog

I am wondering how to make overlay with jQuery on mouse click?
For example I have found this:

```
<script>
  $(".my_overlay_trigger").overlay({
     color: '#fff',
     top: 50
  });
</script>
```

But since I don't know how this actually works, I cannot use it.

What I want?
I want a click of a button 
to run an overlay window that cannot be closed with any kind of buttons. Just "Esc" button may close it. Just like on modal popup boxes...

Any solution for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to adding jquery ui you could refer this

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal.html

look here: http://jsfiddle.net/u8EBJ/

NOTE the src is taken from jqueryui link above